# Forget password link expire, password is updated

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working in magento 1.9.0.1 which has issue with **confirm password not match** in checkout as guest.

I tried to fix it with following code being provided by StackExchange [Magento1.9.1 Please make sure your password match issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311240/magento1-9-1-please-make-sure-your-password-match-issue)

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
$passwordconfirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
//if ($password != $confirmation) {
if (!(($password == $confirmation) ||
    ($password == $passwordconfirmation))) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
}
```

When I use "forget password" to reset the password it breaks the first time, but after reload it shows **Cannot save a new password.
Your password reset link has expired.** but also includes **Your password has been updated.**

Comment: In the link they are using a 3rd party module `IWD Social Login extension` and this is the reason why its not working. Are you using the same module?

Comment: I'm using **BeeShopy_BeeSocial** extension and I tried after disable it but It can't work.

Comment: Forgot password is well working at my local system but when It is uploaded to server it is not working even i check time zone and locale setting

Comment: well the `BeeShopy_BeeSocial` is just for social links and doesn't look like its interfering with your password reset. Have you tried reseting the password in magento admin and use that password to see if that works?

Comment: Password change works using admin panel

Comment: with that changed password can you login via checkout?

Comment: yes I will be able to use that password on onepage checkout

Answer (score 1):

After reading comments and the linked StackExchange(which derives from a 3rd party module).

In Magento 1.9.1.1 the `changepasswordAction` controller is changed from `setConfirmation($password)` to `setPasswordConfirmation($password)`.

If you are still in Magento 1.9.0.1 then you need to make sure your 3rd modules need check the `$customer->getConfirmation()`